# How to disable a USB port in Windows (XP) and make it available only for charging?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, charging

How can I disable a USB port in Windows XP to make it available only for smart phone battery charging?

I don’t want the users to be able to see the USB drive in My Computer, and the USB device should stay disabled in Device Manager.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: depending on the phone, you can disable being able to use it as a USB storage device at the phone, as opposed to the computer.

Answer (score 3):

[This is a common solution.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823732)

Essentially, you disable USB mass storage. What the device is should not be relevant. A smartphone as storage, an external hard drive and a jump drive all pose the same problems, and use the same drivers.

> If a USB storage device is not already installed on the computer, assign
>   the user or the group and the local `SYSTEM` account **Deny** permissions to
>   the following files:
>
> - `%SystemRoot%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf`
> - `%SystemRoot%\Inf\Usbstor.inf`
>
> When you do this, users cannot install a USB storage device on the
>   computer. To assign a user or group **Deny** permissions to the
>   `Usbstor.pnf` and `Usbstor.inf` files, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Start *Windows Explorer*, and then locate the `%SystemRoot%\Inf` folder.
> 2. Right-click the **`Usbstor.pnf`** file, and then click **Properties**.
> 3. Click the **Security** tab.
> 4. In the **Group or user names** list, add the user or group that you want to set **Deny** permissions for.
> 5. In the **Permissions for *UserName or GroupName*** list, click to select the **Deny** check box next to **Full Control**.
>      
>      **Note:** Also add the System account to the **Deny** list.
> 6. In the **Group or user names** list, select the `SYSTEM` account.
> 7. In the **Permissions for *UserName or GroupName*** list, click to select the **Deny** check box next to **Full Control**, and then click **OK**.
> 8. Right-click the **`Usbstor.inf`** file, and then click **Properties**.
> 9. Click the **Security** tab.
> 10. In the **Group or user names** list, add the user or group that you want to set **Deny** permissions for.
> 11. In the **Permissions for *UserName or GroupName*** list, click to select the **Deny** check box next to **Full Control**.
> 12. In the **Group or user names** list, select the `SYSTEM` account.
> 13. In the **Permissions for *UserName or GroupName*** list, click to select the **Deny** check box next to **Full Control**, and then click **OK**.

Comment: thanks. I just found another way to do it by disable Generic Volume under Storage volumes in Device manager as show in below image. But is there any way to disable generic volume using registry? http://s3.postimg.org/4bs6vd683/image.jpg

Comment: Ugh! `code blocks` are not for that...

Comment: @ADTC sometimes it is a necessary evil when the alternative is destroyed formatting: Of course *if you can make it better* then **improve it by all means!**

Comment: @AthomSfere **Done! Followed original article's formatting with some improvements.** I was on mobile 11 hours ago, so the comment was a note to myself to do it when I get to a PC. :) I don't see `code blocks` as a way to preserve any formatting sans line breaks. If you meant the preservation of line breaks, you can easily achieve that in regular text (in Stack Exchange markdown) using double spaces at the end of line or the HTML `<br>` tag.

Comment: BTW for the sake of correctness: For Android smartphones after ICS (or Honeycomb), the claim *"smarphones ... use the same drivers"* is not correct, as these newer devices use MTP/PTP protocols instead of USB mass storage drivers. I think Apple products also do not connect as mass storage as they use proprietary protocols embedded in their iTunes software.